# idea intellij maven project can't make

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

I have maven project. Maven build complete SUCCESS. But i can't make this project.

[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

Project contains one module. Idea can't see dependencies.

```
Error:(3, 38) java: D:\Dropbox\Programming\java\spring\springBook\src\main\java\ch14\validator\ContactTestValidator.java:3: 
package org.springframework.stereotype does not exist
```

POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>springBook</groupId>
<artifactId>springBook</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<!-- Shared version number properties -->
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!--для валидации бинов необходима-->
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!--Spring Data JPA использует его - добавим и пользуемся-->
        <!--API для работы с датами-->
        <!--ch14 validator-->
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!--ch14 validator-->
        <!--API интерфейса JSR-303-->
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!--ch14 validator-->
        <!--API, которая поддерживает интерфейс JSR-303 - BeanValidation-->
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!--для валидации. (@Type...)-->
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Spring framework-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>springBook</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

Could you help me? Unfortunately, I can't add screenshots..
There are screenshots:
http://screencast.com/t/iNaWO9gy
http://screencast.com/t/iBGTyMpgH

Project settings - Libraries - empty;

reimport didn't help;

Comment: Did you add the pom.xml to your maven projects in IntelliJ?
If you did that you shouldnt see empty libraries since they should contain your .jar depentencies

Comment: Have you tried opening the `Maven project` tool window and click on the `Reimport all maven projects` button?

Comment: file->invalidate casches/restart

Comment: Did you set the maven environment variable or did you set maven in the IDE settings? If not, Intellij will not find maven and sometimes screw thins up...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Do the following steps:

1. Find your pom.xml in your files
2. Right click on it --> Maven --> Import
3. Wait for the project to load :D
4. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> (This opens the Projects window.)
5. Go to libraries and see if they are empty (they shouldnt)
6. If they are post your full pom.xml please so I can see the problem
7. If you still have a problem got to File --> Invalidate Caches
   /Restart
8. Go to maven and Reimport All Maven Projects

Comment: Now I have "Cannot reconnect. inspect maven model for resolution problems" on project element

Comment: I've added full pom.xml file;

Comment: there is this tag missing from your pom.xml:
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

Comment: Doing Step 4 and changing the spring-core to 'compile' solved the issue for me. A mix and match of this answer with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488194/cannot-access-org-springframework-core-env-environmentcapable

Comment: In mac OS, what is `ctrl+alt+shift+s`?

Comment: @Penguin: ⌘ + ;

Comment: There is no Maven menu if it's not already recognized as a Maven project. But if you right click the `pom.xml` there should be a `Add as Maven Project` option (or similar). It did the trick for me.

Answer (score 6):

Option `Maven -> Reimport`
should force Intellij to reload all dependencies. Alternatively, as mentioned in comments you can click the `Reimport All Maven Projects` button in `Maven Projects` view.

Comment: reimport didn't help;

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had my own apache-maven-3.5.2 folder and a misconfiguration created my problem. Maybe it's your case too:

In rush, I set the local repository to C:/my/folder/apache-maven-3.5.2/settings.xml, but it must be a folder so Maven didn't allow me to download the dependencies. Then I changed the default (in the picture) and it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open the module dependencies (press F12 on the module), go to `Modules -> Dependencies` and make sure maven imports are part of the of this.

Comment: This is the problem, you're missing your maven dependencies, click the green tick on the right and add the maven dependencies as a dependency of this module.

Answer (score 1):

Try to import the project from sources, if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22956610/1429387) didn't help you.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me.

1. Deleted the maven dependency from my local repository
2. mvn clean install downloaded the dependency again
3. File --> Invalidate Caches/Restart
4. I still saw the compilation error
5. on my mac, I hit option + enter, intellij asked me to add the jar to classpath
6. build -> make project

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same problem, and the issue was small. I had changed the location of settings.xml file of maven and Intellij was picking up the default from C:\users\.m2\settings.xml

So point your maven settings.xml to the correct file as below:
File--> Settings--> Build, Execution, Deployment--> Maven 
then on the right window, override "User settings file" to the settings.xml where you have in your local disk.

If you have installed maven in a non-default location then this file you can find in:
\apache-maven-3.2.3\conf\settings.xml

Answer (score 1):

Right click on `pom.xml` and click `Add as Maven Project`