# cannot access org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapable

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm trying to get a spring bean in a web application using it:

```
WebApplicationContext wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
AClass aClass = (aClass) wac.getBean("aClass");
```

And, when I run compile/test/package with maven, an error occurs:

```
cannot access org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapable
[ERROR] class file for org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapable not found
```

The most strange is that org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapable exists! :/

Basic Project Configuration:

- Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE (There isn't other spring version in classpath)
- Maven 3
- JSF 2.1
- Servlet API 2.5

Any idea is welcome!

Answer (score 8):

Finally, I've solved it! :)

In the pom.xml file, I had to define the scope of spring's dependencies to compile. (Yes, I know that is the default scope of dependencies but for some reason maven was not capable of the job). See a piece of my pom.xml that made the problem disapear:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Note that:

- If you're having this problem, make sure that you're using a spring
  version 3.1 or higher.
- Remember that ${spring.version}, in my case, is 3.1.1.RELEASE.

I hope that it helps more people.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the exact same issue: Maven complains about `org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapable`, even with the file there, inside the JAR: `C:\Users\fabio\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.3.12.RELEASE\spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar`.

The solution in my case was to delete the `.m2` folder, so that Maven downloaded all the JARs again. Maybe it was some corrupted file.

I hope it helps someone!

Comment: Instead of the entire `~/.m2` directory (I really didn't want to download the entire internet ... again.), I just removed the `~/.m2/repository/org/springframework`, but I'm guessing I could have just removed the `~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core` directory.

Comment: I can confirm that `rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core` solved the problem

Comment: as @DavidAvendasora said, deleting just the springframework folder worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Me too face this issue. I used Spring 4.1.6 with maven 3 along with RabbitMQ.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency forced tomcat to die and showing these issue. I havn't gotten why it is making trouble. but finally I explicitly include jar in lib folder and this is how I resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency to the pom.xml .You can fixed it.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>        
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I imported a  project from GitHub without  checking its  spring-boot  version had caused me  the  same problem, thus changing  spring-boot   version has resolved  my  problem, I was using  version **1.1.4** moving to **2.2.5** (or latest releases ) will download all the needed  dependencies

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this folder:

```
\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core
```

from your `.m2` and run:

```
mvn clean install -U -X
```