# Adding flink hbase connector dependency

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-3, apache-flink, flink-streaming, intellij-idea-2016

I am trying to connect with Hbase and Druid from flink. I have added following dependency in intellij.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-hbase_2.10

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-hbase_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and https://github.com/druid-io/tranquility. Seems maven central has only version [0.8.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.druid/tranquility-flink_2.11/0.8.2) rather than 0.9.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.druid</groupId>
  <artifactId>tranquility-flink_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But intellij is saying dependency not found. How do I add this dependency?

Comment: From what I see, they have not released 0.9.0 version, its just someone updated the readme documentation, please check again -
 https://github.com/druid-io/tranquility/releases

Comment: @BiplobBiswas Yes, The documentation is not correct (readme). But still can't import 0.8.2 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of trying, I [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22956610/2214674) added library:

1. Find your pom.xml in your files
2. Right click on it --> Maven --> Import
3. Wait for the project to load :D
4. Press ctrl+alt+shift+s (This opens the Projects window.)

Then click green + sign to import maven library.